# Unable to match using regex negative lookahead?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match the following string using regular expressions in Java:

```
suspicious url test' xts#dfd
```

I don't want the regex to match if there is a quote, (`'`) 
This is what I'm using.

```
suspicious url\s.*(?!')
```

When i use this I match the whole string.

Comment: This depends completely on what kind of regex you are using. Are these POSIX? EREGex? Perl? Sed? what?

Comment: @terdon java...it uses java regex to match it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Java programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the .* will match everything before the look ahead even happens. If you just want to make sure that a ' does not follow until the end of the line try:

```
suspicious url\s[^']*$
```